# Arabic string , which is send to hotmail email via php mail, is demonstrated in strange symbols in when viewed inside hotmail email

Tags: php, html, email

yahoo mail seems to be able to display both variables that use $_Post as well as variables declared without this method 
But in hotmail, only variables declared without the $_Post are displayed in the email

I have tried to include `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` in both php and html pages but with no success

The text below is the email which is send to hotmail

```
  المرسل

    الاسم: &#1576;&#1588;&#1575;&#1585;  التعليق:&#1607;&#1584;&#1575; &#1578;&#1593;&#1604;&#1610;&#1602;
```

the php code is below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title> php file</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

  <body dir="rtl">

<?php
$fname= $_POST['firstName'];
$lname= $_POST['lastName'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$from = "المرسل ";


  $msg = "الاسم: $fname\n"."التعليق:$comment\n";

  $subject= "Visitor comment";

  $to= "example@hotmail.com";

  mail($to,$subject,$msg, $from);




?>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please point what might be the problem ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `$_POST`. That is a simple variable, no magic there, except that it is a superglobal variable. You issue is with encoding inside headers _and_ with your wrong usage of the `mail()` function. I suggest you take a look at the documentation of that function. As a fourth argument an _array_ of _headers_ is expected. `"المرسل "` certainly is not an array and not a valid header entry for an email. You should consult how an email message actually is composed.

Comment: @arkascha for some reason , variables declared using $_Post are not sent to the hotmail email properly. I doubt too that there is a problem in it because it does transport form data to my script when I send to yahoo email

Comment: Have you bothered at all to check a documentation? Have you taken a look at how emails are coded internally at all? I doubt that. You expect magic to happen. This will not work. PHP is a simple scripting language. We are talking about strings here. Not magic.

Comment: @arkascha I was hoping some one would point what might be the problem so that I would look it up. Not looking for the easy way.

Comment: Sorry, but didn't I do that? I suggested several times that you take a look into the documentation. Where else would you want to "look it up"? 1. you have to fix how you use the ``mail()`` function, you violate its signature and 2. you have to learn how an email message actually is composed internally. A good start for this is either to read the documentation or to simply take a look at the _source code_ of an existing email message you received. Especially one containing arabic characters.

Answer (score 0):

headers (like from)  should be formatted according to [RFC-2048](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2048.txt)

also you'll need [mime encoding](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) for the email body 
if you want to use anything other than ASCII in the email body

I not aware of an easy way to do this well, but if you di a search on those terms there's plenty of simple code that solves subsets of the full problem space

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

between `<head>` tags of the html file which $_Post is using

w t5alesh wa7ad 3rs zy sa7eb elta3lekat fo2 ynaked 3alek ;-)

Answer (score -2):

This could be that the e-mail does not support unicode charecters, Arabic in particular is not as widely supported as say, Japanese or Russian, so you would have to change the formatting in order to have it display properly. Also, Arabic is read from right to left unlike English.

Comment: Certainly an E-Mail message can contain UTF sequences.